# Toggle TreeView row selection individually with each click

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk2, gtktreeview

I'm using PyGTK 2.0's TreeView backed by a ListStore to create a table of selectable items. I need to select and deselect individual rows by single clicking anywhere on the row. Clicking a row should toggle the highlight and the value of a checkbox only for that row.

I've created the TreeView with multiple selection and a column for the checkboxes, but I can't toggle the selection on an individual row without holding Control. I tried to connect a select function to the view so that it would at least toggle the checkboxes, but the function does not work [as described in the tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TreeSelections.html#sec-TreeSelectionFunction):

```
    self.dataview = gtk.TreeView(store)
    self.dataview.get_selection().set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)
    self.dataview.get_selection().set_select_function(self.on_row_selected, None)

def on_row_selected(self, selection, model, path, is_selected, data):
    print selection
    print model
    print path
    print is_selected
    print data
    model.set_value(path, 0, is_selected)
```

Triggering the select function produces an error:

```
TypeError: on_row_selected() takes exactly 6 arguments (3 given)
```

Replacing the function arguments with `*args` shows that only `path` and `data` are provided.

Besides the behavior of `set_select_function`, what's the best approach to toggling row selection with single clicks, and how do I sync that with a column in my data model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly what I asked for but I finally got the interaction I wanted using [`gtk.TreeViewColumn.set_cell_data_func`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktreeviewcolumn.html#method-gtktreeviewcolumn--set-cell-data-func). This allows me to specify a function that will be called whenever a cell is to be rendered. I used it to apply a custom style across the whole row based on its data, and then used single-selection clicks just to toggle the value.

```
    self.view = gtk.TreeView(store)
    self.view.get_selection().set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_SINGLE)
    self.view.get_selection().set_select_function(self.on_row_selected)
    ...
    renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
    for idx, heading in enumerate(heading_list):
        col = gtk.TreeViewColumn(None, renderer, text=idx)
        col.set_cell_data_func(renderer, self.cell_data_func)

...

def cell_data_func(self, column, cell, model, it):
    if model.get(it, self.select_index)[0]:
        # apply selected style
    else:
        # apply normal style

def on_row_selected(self, data):
    path = data[0]
    iter = self.model.get_iter(path)
    val = self.model.get_value(iter, self.select_index)
    self.model.set_value(iter, self.select_index, not val)
```